# Laravel 5 Routing Issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel. My problem is that If i try to access a route Like this : http://localhost/shivani/public/sitehome  , It works perfectly fine.

but If I try to access it like this : localhost/shivani/public/sitehome/

It redirects to http://localhost/sitehome and says "Object not found".

Comment: are you using apache or nginx or php artisan serve?

Answer (score 0):

is there a routes.php kicking about in your project?

Posting the relevant sections would likely help.

Although I assume its something to do with how your development environment is set up.

Comment: I have only these routes in my routes.php Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::controller('sitehome','website');
Route::get('post/{id}','website@singlepost');

Comment: I did'nt configure any enviournment as yet...Just working with the fresh install as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Some months ago i had same question and i found this solution :

in public/.htaccess at line 9:

> 1. Just remove that line. Laravel should automatically point to the correct URLs, and some misspellings with the trailing slash shouldn't
>      matter too much.
> 2. The other solution is to change it to: RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /app/public/$1 [L,R=301]. The major problem with that is that this
>      will break your app in production (assuming it won't have "app/public"
>      in it).

here is [source](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=15922)